# How do I push div wrapper if floating sidebar taller than it

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/NuzDj/

If you resize windows size, `sidebar` overlapping the `wrapper` & `footer`.

How do I push the `wrapper` height automatic when sidebar overlap them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After working this out for about the past half hour, I figured the easiest way to do this would be manually check for the point of scroll past the end of the content at which point removing the fixed class from sidebar allowing content which passed after this to show as intended, however to sneakily hack it to make it appear as though it was still in the same place a margin-top is applied aswell to the sidebar to keep it sitting at it's end point after scrolling to the end of content.

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeymagic/yxh8m/3/

with this bit of jquery magic:

```
 var sidebarheight = $('.sidebar').height();
 var contentheight = $('.content').height();

 if (y > (contentheight - sidebarheight)) {
     $('.sidebar').css({marginTop: contentheight - sidebarheight - 10});
     $('.sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
 }
 else 
    {
     $('.sidebar').css({marginTop: '0'});
     $('.sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    }
```

this is inserted inbetween this

```
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y >= top) {
      $('.sidebar').addClass('fixed');
```

and this:

```
} else {
      $('.sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});​
```

Comment: Position Fixed is what all those annoying 'keep this menu in your face' scripts that you come across on maybe even 33.33% on the internet should use. The fact that they update the position of a block per millisecond is just too slow and looks laggy. Position Fixed === lag fixed :) Upvote for you, mr. @MagicDev!

Comment: hahaha thankyou,Yeah i'd agree that alot of pages use this really badly but hey, alot of devs just don't know better- although I wish there was a simpler way of fixing this sort of an issue than resorting to a bunch jquery; css4?